# Change and apply text .first after sed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, sed

I'm currently upgrading rails 2.3 application to rails 3.2. I've used sed to replace certian text to all the files but how can I append after a sed?

```
User(anymodel).find(:first, options)
```

change to:

```
User(anymodel).where(options).first
```

How may I able to achieve this using sed?

Comment: Not sure that sed is the right choice unless you're testing well. I'd rather change then manually than have lots of error pages in production.

Comment: I'm currently editing 100-200 of files due to upgrade. I was thinking of file manipulation for a faster way to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
sed 's/^\(User\.\)[^(]*(:\([^,]*\), \(.*\)$/\1where(\3.\2/'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'User.find(:first, :condition => {:is_used => 1 })' | sed 's/^\(User\.\)[^(]*(:\([^,]*\), \(.*\)$/\1where(\3.\2/'
User.where(:condition => {:is_used => 1 }).first
```

**Update:**

```
$ echo '<% User(anymodel).find(:first, options) %>' | sed 's/^\(<% *User[^.]*\.\)find(:\([^,]*\), \(.*\)\( \+%>\)$/\1where(\3.\2\4/'
<% User(anymodel).where(options).first %>
```

Comment: Yeah but that worked but considering this. How can I reuse that code if ever I have something like this:

Model.find(:first, options)

Comment: so you want a single command to work for both. does the file contains only the lines which starts with `Model` or `User`?

Comment: You mean this `echo 'Model.find(:first, options)' | sed 's/^\([^.]*\.\)[^(]*(:\([^,]*\), \(.*\)$/\1where(\3.\2/'`

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my concern specific. I have conditions in which Model(User, Employee, etc..).find(:first, options) to become Model(User, Employee, etc..).where(options).first

Comment: this one `$ echo 'User(anymodel).find(:first, options)' | sed 's/^\(User[^.]*\.\)find(:\([^,]*\), \(.*\)/\1where(\3.\2/'`

Comment: Yup this worked. Thanks. But how about if it is inside <% %>?

Comment: I mean it like this <% User(anymodel).find(:first, options) %>

Comment: then this one `$ echo '<% User(anymodel).find(:first, options) %>' | sed 's/^\(<% *User[^.]*\.\)find(:\([^,]*\), \(.*\)\( \+%>\)$/\1where(\3.\2\4/'`